# How to determine the time that the device was not being used for?

Tags: android

My application should detect whether the user was sleeping to start itself with a welcome message when the user wakes up and powers up his phone for the first time in the morning, afternoon, or whenever he wakes up, by pressing the power putton and entering the pattern on the homescreen or pin or whatever.

I want to do this by measuring the time the device was used the last time. I presume 8 hours of sleep, so if 8 hours passed since the last switching off, the next time the mobile phone is being switched on, the application starts(respectively a function inside).

The screen going on because of an alarm or anything but user interaction should not count.

I looked at logcat and it gave me the useful information `I/PowerManagerService: Going to sleep due to power button`. So a PowerManagerServiceListener could be a way. I found https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html but it is for actively keeping the display on, not for passively reporting it.

Another candidate is `KeyguardViewMediator: onStartedGoingToSleep(2)` and `KeyguardServiceDelegate: onScreenTurnedOff()`.

Sure, I could create a polling application, that looks through logcat, but that sounds like a strongly battery draining approach.

Which performance friendly way is there to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you are interested in a granularity of hours. Then you can schedule a repeating alarm every hour (see [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)), save the time in a Shared Preference, receive a `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, compare the times and decide what to do.

However, I guess a lot of users don't turn their devices off, so I would try to find out if the assumption your approach is based on is valid.

You can also try `getDetectedActivity()` from [Snapshot Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/SnapshotApi#getDetectedActivity(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) and check if [DetectedActivity](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity) is for example `STILL` at some specified interval.

Comment: It is about the means to an end. How do you measure the time between interactions with the device as in tapping the screen, pushing the power button...